# Как выполнить SQL запрос в Yii2 на обновление данных?

Tags: yii, yii2

Как выполнить SQL запрос в Yii2  на обновление данных?

```
UPDATE  table_name  SET  forum=300  WHERE  forum=200;
```

Пытаюсь так, но не получается:

```
$customer = Account::find()
                 ->select(['salt_activ'])
                 ->where(['forum' => 200])
                 ->one();
                  $customer->forum = 300;
                  $customer->update();
```

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно выполнить "сырой" SQL запрос, то отлично подойдет данный вариант

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE account SET forum=:newValue WHERE forum=:oldValue', [':newValue' => 300, ':oldValue' => 200])->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

В возвращаемой модели, функцией `findOne`, нет атрибута `forum`, т.к. указан `select`, в котором нет этого атрибута. Поэтому `$customer->forum` - вызовет ошибку несуществующего атрибута. Насколько помню в *Yii2* нет `update()`.

```
$customer = Account::find()
     ->where(['forum' => 200])
     ->one();
$customer->forum = 300;
$customer->save();
```

При использование `Yii::$app->db->createCommand(...)` модель не будет участвовать в обработке записи, что очень часто имеет большую важность, потому что не будет произведена валидация данных, а это нарушение безопасности.